How to parse and render large HTML string (>3MB) inside React
I am stuck at one frontend problem and wanted to know if you have faced any ever.
So the problem is I have a huge HTML (> 3 MB) to render into my DOM. However , if I do it altogether the DOM crashes.
I also need to DOM Purify & parse it before rendering it.
I tried splitting it into chunks and rendering but that breaks the HTML being rendered.
The problem cant be solved using lazy loading or so because the HTML chunk I am getting altogether from a presigned URL link.
I was trying if I could break it into chunks and re-render react everytime the array is upadted with the new chunk .
Something like this.

    useEffect(() => {
        if (emailBody) {
            const chunkSize = 1000; // Adjust chunk size as needed
            for (let i = 0; i < emailBody.length; i += chunkSize) {
                console.log('emailbody', emailBody.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
                setTimeout(() => {
                setBodyChunks((bodyChunks) => [...bodyChunks, emailBody.slice(i, i + chunkSize)]);
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    }, [emailBody]);

And render it like

                          <div onClick={(e) => handleEmailPreviewClick(e)} className={'email-preview--body'}>
                                {bodyChunks.map((chunk, index) => (
                                    <div key={index}>{parse(DOMPurify.sanitize(chunk))}</div>
                                ))}
                            </div>


Hopefully native DOMParser API with parseFromString method can handle that amount of html string, after which when you get a structured DOM, you can split it to right chunks so it won't break original HTML structure, or just append parsed document inside your existing DOM element.

Rendering HTML "chunks" only works if the chunks represent a valid / consistent part of HTML. -- I recomment to do parse( DOMPurify.sanitize( emailBody ) ) only once, inside a useMemo, instead of on every render. -- Try to make layouting as easy as possible for the browser, e.g. make email-preview--body a fixed size box (that might or might not help).
